# Good Windows Azure Storage Manager

Tags: windows, azure, storage, explorer

I have been using cloud storage studio (trial):

http://www.cerebrata.com/Products/CloudStorageStudio/

but it is about to expire.  Does anybody know of a similar (free) product?

I need something that allows me to delete all of the tables as I am creating thousands of tables and want a tool to delete them without too much hassle.

I've also tried Azure Storage Explorer 5:

http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/

however it doesn't have the bulk delete option like cloud storage studio.

Any help with locating a decent Windows Azure Storage Explorer would be appreciated.

Comment: I have forgotten the functionality available in this one but you can have a look into this one: http://azureblobstudio.codeplex.com/ . Also, not sure about bulk delete.

Comment: cheers ruchit I downloaded but it only has blob storage functionality, not queue or table stuff.

Comment: if you are looking for fast and easy storage table browser, try this: https://github.com/amithegde/AzureTableBrowser

Answer (score 1):

[TableXplorer](http://clumsyleaf.com/products/tablexplorer) is really a joy to use (same applies to the other apps by ClumsyLeaf).

But if you want to do some (automated) bulk deletes of tables, you might want to look at the [AzureCommandLineTools](https://github.com/RobBlackwell/AzureCommandLineTools). This allows you to do operations on storage with a batch file / powershell.

Comment: thanks sandrino, i've been using azure sdk for node.js, I'm thinking of just writing some javascript to loop over queues, tables, blobs and delete them.